# How do I ignore same words in a string (Java)?

Tags: java, string, char, return

I want to find how many words there are in a string, but ignore the similar words in it.

For example, the main method should return 8 instead of 9.

I want it to be a method which takes one parameter s of type String and returns an int value. And I’m only allowed to use the basics, so HashMaps, ArrayLists, loops, and *if* statements are ***not*** allowed. Only charAt, length, and substring are allowed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

countUniqueWords("A long long time ago, I can still remember");

public static int countUniqueWords(String str) {
    char[] sentence = str.toCharArray();
    boolean inWord = false;
    int wordCt = 0;
    for (char c : sentence) {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            if (!inWord) {
                wordCt++;
                inWord = true;
            }
        } else {
            inWord = false;
        }
    }
    return wordCt;
}
```

Comment: 1. I don't know how would you distinguish the words in the string? Use space char or `,` ?  2. what is similar words ?

Comment: To complete this task without a mutable list is not very idiomatic, how do you plan on storing the unique set of words?  I guess you can use a string with comma delimited values.

Answer (score 3):

Don't force yourself to limited options, and learn the Streaming API. Your question is as simple as:

```
public static long countUniqueWords(String str) {
    var str2 = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "").replaceAll(" +", " ");
    return Arrays.stream(str2.split(" "))
            .distinct()
            .count();
}
```

1. *[Optional step]* Get get rid of all non alphanumeric chars
2. Split the string per empty slot
3. Remove duplicates
4. Add them together

Comment: I've only learnt the basics, so Streaming API is out of my coding capability at the moment. Is there a way i can improve my code withdout using Stream?

Comment: You can write your own for-loop of course. But then, you still need a temporary variable (array/list/map/whatever) to keep track of the duplicates. So you will end with something @Naveed Khan wrote!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static int countUniqueWords(String words) {
    // Add all the words to a list
    List<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(words);
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String s = in.next();
        array.add(s);
    }

    // Save per word the amount of duplicates
    HashMap<String, Integer> listOfWords = new HashMap<>();
    Iterator<String> itr = array.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        String next = itr.next();
        String prev = listOfWords.getOrDefault(next, 0);
        listOfWords.put(next, prev + 1);
    }

    // Grab the size of all known words
    return listOfWords.size();
}

public static void main(String args[]) { 
    int count = countUniqueWords("A long long time ago, I can still remember");
    System.out.println("The number of unique words: " + count);
}
```

Comment: im not allowed to use hashkeys :(

Answer (score 0):

To ignore same words in a string, you can use a combination of the split and distinct methods from the Java Stream API.

```
    // Define the input string
String input = "This is a test string with some repeating words";

// Split the string into an array of words
String[] words = input.split("\\s+");

// Use the distinct method to remove duplicate words from the array
String[] distinctWords = Arrays.stream(words).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);

// Print the distinct words
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(distinctWords));
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work, not sure about its scalability, though.

```java
int countUniqueWords(String str) {
    String set = "";
    boolean found;
    for (String wordA : str.split("\\s+")) {
        if (set.isEmpty())
            set = wordA;
        else {
            found = false;
            for (String wordB : set.split("\\s+")) {
                if (wordB.equalsIgnoreCase(wordA)) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) set += " " + wordA;
        }
    }
    return set.split(" ").length;
}
```

Ideally, you want to use a `Pattern` and `Matcher`, so you can use word-boundary and word capture, `\b([\w&&[^\d]]+)\b`.
This would remove any words that may contain numbers, and negate any isolated punctuation marks from being counted.